# SQLite compiler errors

Tags: visual-c++, sqlite

When including "sqlite3.c" into my project, I get lots of compiler errors:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type "_ht"    d:\...\sqlite3.c    line 19556
...
fatal error C1003: Errors in the program are too numerous to allow recovery. The compiler must terminate.
```

When inlcuding "sqlite3.c" into an empty test project, I have no problems. I compared project settings and there are no big differences between the two projects.

How can I troubleshoot this problem? Is there anyone who had the same issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the existing [DLL](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)?

Comment: yes - I don't want to use the dll. Including "sqlite.c" instead of using it as a lib is a common option, which is described on the sqlite website and works for the test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not including all its header files (or maybe you're trying to build C as C++). Don't Do That. Better yet, build it into a library (or use someone else's build) and just include the built version in your project.

Comment: yes, I included it in a C++ project. I an external lib the only solution for this? Thanks

Comment: It is recommended to use the amalgamation source code file: "sqlite3.c" in all projects (c and c++): http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html

Comment: I now built a static lib and linked this lib to my application. It works now. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the `sqlite3.c` file in your project and select `Properties`. Go to

```
C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As => "Compile as C Code (/TC)"
```

This solves the issue. Make sure to set that under all of your Configurations and Platforms.

I ran into the same issue. I'm creating a plugin and so compiling in sqlite rather than having to distribute an additional DLL is beneficial, and this is less work than creating an additional project to build a static lib.